# Why is the favicon different in the HNQ sidebar

Tags: bug, design

The banner logo shown at the top of every page, which is similar to the logo shown in the HNQ list (if you click through to to see all of them), but different to the logo shown in the HNQ sidebar. Why is this?

Edit: I've just noticed that the icon in the notifications tray is the same as the one in the HNQ sidebar, so both logos seem about as common.

Comment: What do you mean with "the banner logo shown at the top of every page"?

Answer (score 3):

I think this should be fixed and the icons should be matched.

There is no good reason why the logos have to look completely different, given that they don't even visibly differ in their size (the 48x48 logo just has more blank space around it while the 32x32 one actually even appears slightly bigger). Sec.SE seems to be the only site that has entirely different icons at these different sizes.

32 x 32:

[image: 48x48]

48 x 48:

[image: 48x48]